# SQL Statement for querying an age range from a dob

Tags: sql, range

Greetings. I have a table called "persons". It have the dob as a date datatype of course. I calculate the age with the following statement:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%Y' ) - DATE_FORMAT( fecha_nac,  '%Y' ) - 
( DATE_FORMAT(NOW( ) ,  '00-%m-%d' ) < DATE_FORMAT( fecha_nac,  '00-%m-%d' ) ) 
AS edad
```

But when I try to query a specific age with the following statement it gives me errors:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%Y' ) - DATE_FORMAT( fecha_nac,  '%Y' ) - 
( DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '00-%m-%d' ) < DATE_FORMAT( fecha_nac,  '00-%m-%d' ) ) 
AS edad WHERE edad BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

Of course it gives me erros because the "edad" column doesn't exists. I need a sql query to list all the people within an age range from a dob. I don't know how to make this query please help.

Comment: For others who may try to help, I'd just like to note that `fecha_nac` means `birth_date` and `edad` is `age`.

Comment: which database are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    WITH TBL AS
    (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '%Y' ) - DATE_FORMAT( fecha_nac,  '%Y' ) - ( DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  '00-%m-%d' ) < DATE_FORMAT( fecha_nac,  '00-%m-%d' ) ) AS edad
FROM Persons
    )

    SELECT Edad FROM TBL WHERE Edad BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

The above is SQL Server. You can use Temp Tables to accomplish the same thing in other databases as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will search about Temp Tables

Comment: The above is definitely not SQL Server. There is no `DATE_FORMAT` function or `NOW` there,

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't allow the WITH construction. If all you need is the people, and not their exact age at the moment, you can move the test into the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT nombre, otras_cosas FROM personas 
WHERE NOW() 
 BETWEEN (CAST(fecha_nac) AS DATETIME) + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
   AND (CAST(fecha_nac) AS DATETIME) + INTERVAL 50 YEAR;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this without temp tables.

One is to repeat the calculation in your where

```
SELECT yourtable.nombre, yourtable.otras_cosas,
      Date_format(Now(), '%Y') - Date_format(fecha_nac, '%Y') - ( 
              Date_format(Now(), '00-%m-%d') < Date_format(fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d' 
                                               ) ) AS 
       edad 
FROM   yourtable 
WHERE  Date_format(Now(), '%Y') - Date_format(fecha_nac, '%Y') - ( 
              Date_format(Now(), '00-%m-%d') < Date_format(fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d' 
                                               ) ) BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

The other is to use an inline view

```
SELECT   t.nombre, t.otras_cosas, t.edad 
FROM   (SELECT  nombre, otras_cosas, Date_format(Now(), '%Y') - Date_format(fecha_nac, '%Y') - ( 
                              Date_format(Now(), '00-%m-%d') < 
                              Date_format(fecha_nac, '00-%m-%d') ) AS edad 
        FROM   yourtable) t 
WHERE  t.edad BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

Comment: The inline view version is good, but you probably need to add a name or id field to the `SELECT` along with the age. Also, the calculation would be a good choice for a stored procedure.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus good point. I've added some additional hypothetical fields (shamelessly stolen from your answer) to better demonstrate what's going on

Comment: Nice answer. I will use the second query. Thanks a lot for the help everyone.